# Backwards compatibility support for old COM objects in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My C# project is referencing a COM object from company 'HelloWorld' which is at version 2, and contains definitions for 2 methods `HelloWorld.Foo()` and `HelloWorld.Bar()`.

If I then unregister this COM component, and register 'HelloWorld' version 1, which just contains `HelloWorld.Foo()` (and not `HelloWorld.Bar()`), obviously the project will not compile as it will generate a compile time error along the lines of

> HelloWorldApi does not contain a definition for 'Bar() and no
>   extension method...`.

Is there any way to somehow work around this without commenting out all the code referencing this non-existent method?

Comment: It is a very strange myth that this is somehow easier to do in COM than it is in C#.  It is not, quite the opposite, a missing method is very likely to crash the program with a ratty E_NOINTERFACE error.  Or worse, a completely undiagnosable AccessViolationException.  Or worse, much worse, calling the complete wrong method and not getting an exception.  You can use the *dynamic* keyword in C# to fool the compiler.  That works for COM objects as well.  But do your end user a favor and don't give him a rope to hang himself.